# Running plain sql in Slick 3.1.0

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to run plain SQL with slick 3.1.0.

The following works:

```
   val q = sql"select name from users".as[String]
```

however if my sql is in a variable:

```
   val string2 : String = "select name from users"
```

how do I execute string2 using sql prefix? This doesn't work:

```
   sql+string2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interpolation within the string:

```
val q = sql"#$string2"
```

The `#$` interpolator will use the *literal* string you're interpolating, so don't use it for user input - it won't quote or anything.

See [this section of the docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/sql.html#splicing-literal-values) for more details.